# Flutter support for IKEv2 PSK

Tags: flutter, mobile, protocols, router

I need to create a mobile VPN app that requires to use IKEv2-PSK connection between the router.
I've searched for ages for flutter packages that supports IKEv2-PSK but unfortunately as far as I know, I counld't find a package that supports this protocol to develop.

My question is,

1. Are there any flutter packages that supports to develop IKEv2-PSK?
2. If not, are there any other solutions?

Thank you so much.